# Differentiate multiple row cells with same id

Tags: javascript, php

I have empty textarea (Note1, Note2, Note3, Note4) and input text (Order level, Qty Level) on my table. How to detect which cell of textarea or input text using onchange method? I have script trigger onchange but it only trigger the alert message on the first row of table td.

For example, if I add text on the 2nd row of Note1 textarea, it won't alert message. Since the table is loop, how to differentiate between cells? Because all note1 textarea using the same id but have multiple row?

Here my code:

```
<table id="table1" class="table table-bordered"> 
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th style="display:none;">Stock Code</th>
       <th>Stock Name</th>
       <th>Note 1</th>
       <th>Note 2</th>
       <th>Note 3</th>
       <th>Note 4</th>
       <th>Order Level</th>
       <th>Qty Level</th>
       <th>Balance</th>  
       <th>Purchase Price</th>  
       <th>UOM</th>                    

       @for ($i=0; $i<=12; $i++)
         <th><?php echo date('Y/m', strtotime('-'.$i.' month', strtotime($getDate)));?></th>
       @endfor                                          
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Foreach loop from db -->
    @foreach ($query as $val)     
      <tr>                    
        <td style="display:none;">{{ $val->StockCode }}</td>
        <td class="text-nowrap align-middle">{{ $val->StockName }}</td>
        <td><textarea rows="2" cols="10" id="note1" class="align-middle"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea rows="2" cols="10" id="note2" class="align-middle"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea rows="2" cols="10" id="note3" class="align-middle"></textarea></td>
        <td><textarea rows="2" cols="10" id="note4" class="align-middle"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="orderlevel" class="text-right"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="qtylevel" class="text-right"></td>
        <td class="text-right align-middle">{{ number_format($val->CurrentBalance, 2) }}</td>
        <td class="text-right align-middle">{{ number_format($val->PurchasePrice, 2) }}</td>
        <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ $val->BaseUOM }}</td>

        @for ($i=1; $i<=13; $i++)
          <?php 
            //looping variables
            $Qty = 'Qty'.$i;
            $Date = 'Date'.$i;
          ?>
           <td class="text-right align-middle">                                    
             @if($val->$Qty > 0) 
             <a id="viewdetails" data-toggle="modal" 
                data-productid="{{$val->Id}}"
                data-productname="{{$val->StockName}}"
                data-getdate="{{date('Y-m', strtotime($val->$Date))}}"
                                    href="#" data-target="#dataModal">{{ number_format($val->$Qty, 2) }}</a>
             @endif
           </td>                                                 
         @endfor 
       </tr> 
       @endforeach  
       <!-- End Foreach loop -->                     
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#note1").change(function(){                 
    var stockid = document.getElementById("stockid").value;                    
    var stockname = document.getElementById("stockname").value;                    
    var note1 = document.getElementById("note1").value;      

    alert("The text entered is "+note1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Use `class` instead of `id`.

Comment: @AtalPrateek use different class name for each textarea and input text?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="table1" class="table table-bordered"> 
<thead>
 <tr>
   <th style="display:none;">Stock Code</th>
   <th>Stock Name</th>
   <th>Note 1</th>
   <th>Note 2</th>
   <th>Note 3</th>
   <th>Note 4</th>
   <th>Order Level</th>
   <th>Qty Level</th>
   <th>Balance</th>  
   <th>Purchase Price</th>  
   <th>UOM</th>                    

   @for ($i=0; $i<=12; $i++)
     <th><?php echo date('Y/m', strtotime('-'.$i.' month', strtotime($getDate)));?></th>
   @endfor                                          
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!-- Foreach loop from db -->
    @foreach ($query as $val)     
  <tr>                    
    <td style="display:none;">{{ $val->StockCode }}</td>
    <td class="text-nowrap align-middle">{{ $val->StockName }}</td>
    <td><textarea rows="2" cols="10" class="note align-middle" data-something="1_<?php echo $val->StockCode; ?>"></textarea></td>
    <td><textarea rows="2" cols="10" class="note align-middle" data-something="2_<?php echo $val->StockCode; ?>"></textarea></td>
    <td><textarea rows="2" cols="10" class="note align-middle" data-something="3_<?php echo $val->StockCode; ?>"></textarea></td>
    <td><textarea rows="2" cols="10" class="note align-middle" data-something="4_<?php echo $val->StockCode; ?>"></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="orderlevel" class="text-right"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="qtylevel" class="text-right"></td>
    <td class="text-right align-middle">{{ number_format($val->CurrentBalance, 2) }}</td>
    <td class="text-right align-middle">{{ number_format($val->PurchasePrice, 2) }}</td>
    <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ $val->BaseUOM }}</td>

    @for ($i=1; $i<=13; $i++)
      <?php 
        //looping variables
        $Qty = 'Qty'.$i;
        $Date = 'Date'.$i;
      ?>
       <td class="text-right align-middle">                                    
         @if($val->$Qty > 0) 
         <a id="viewdetails" data-toggle="modal" 
            data-productid="{{$val->Id}}"
            data-productname="{{$val->StockName}}"
            data-getdate="{{date('Y-m', strtotime($val->$Date))}}"
                                href="#" data-target="#dataModal">{{ number_format($val->$Qty, 2) }}</a>
         @endif
       </td>                                                 
     @endfor 
   </tr> 
   @endforeach  
   <!-- End Foreach loop -->                     
 </tbody>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".note").change(function(){  
    var numberAndStockCode = $(this).data("something")
    numberANdStockCode = numberAndStockCode.split('_')
    var stockid = numberAndStockCode[1];                   
    var note1 = document.getElementById("note1").value;      

    alert("Note Number and StockCode" + numberAndStockCode[0] + ' ' + numberAndStockCode[1]);
  });
});
```

There might be some syntax error related to php, but the concept is, to have click event on class, and read which element is clicked using data attribute of html element.

Comment: If I look at your code, I have notice that the value that will display on the alert message is based on `data-someting` value. What if I want to display what I've entered on the textarea on the alert message? How to do that?

Comment: $(this).val(), if u want to know other methods also, pls put a breakpoint at this line and see this element in the browser console, jQuery has lot of other methods